# Linux/Cut set f2 in place of f1 if f1 is empty

Tags: sed, cut

i have the following problem at work:

we have a xml file from which we read infos like hostname, address and os via xmlstarlet and redirect them into a separate file.

this is the Script:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//host" -m "hostnames/hostname" -v "@name" -b -o "|" -v "address[@addrtype='ipv4']/@addr" -o "|" -v "os/osmatch[1]/@name" -n nmap.xml > newfile
```

now we have 3 infos each line separated by a | like

```
imahost|192.168.50.6|windows
```

some servers do not have a hostname but only the ip and the os like

```
|192.168.50.7|windows
```

then we cut the hostname and the ip out from the file where f1 is hostname and f2 is ip like:

```
cat newfile | cut -d"|" -f1,2
```

it looks like this

```
imahost|192.168.50.6
|192.168.50.7
...
```

if a hostname is not available as in the second line the ip should be inserted in the first position like

```
imahost|192.168.50.6
192.168.50.7|192.168.50.7
...
```

how do we do this? ^^

i thank you in advance for every helpful answer

Comment: `sed -E 's/\|[^|]*$//;s/^\|([^|]*)/\1|\1/' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` can handle empty columns:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1==""{$1=$2} {print $1,$2}' file
```

Set input and output field separator to `|`. If first column is empty copy content of second column to first column. In any case print first and second row.

Output:

```
imahost|192.168.50.6
192.168.50.7|192.168.50.7
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1==""{$1=$2} {print $1,$2}' file  Its worked ty :D